# get Session key laravel login event listener

Tags: php, laravel, session, events, listener

I am doing a small laravel project , 
on LoginController i am setting a data to a session in the authenticated function , 
it is well saved , below the code :

```
   protected function authenticated(Request $request)
    {
    session(['lan' => $request->input('lan')]);
    session(['lat' => $request->input('lat')]);
   }
```

but when i try to read it in the listener it i got an empty data , below my code :

```
public function handle(Login $event)
{
    $lat=app('request')->session()->get('lat');
    Storage::disk ('local')->append ('lat__.txt', "lat:\r\n" . $lat);   
}
```

can some one help me ?
thanks

Comment: Make sure `lan` and `lat` are actually in the request in your authenticated method, because `$request->input()` returns `null` if they are not defined.

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

```
use Session;

 protected function authenticated(Request $request)
 {
   Session::put('lan',$request->input('lan'));
   Session::put('lat',$request->input('lat'));
 }
```

or you can do :

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request)
 {
   $request->session->put('lan',$request->input('lan'));
   $request->session->put('lat',$request->input('lat'));
 }
```

inside your listener :

```
use Session;

public function handle(Login $event)
{
    $lat=Session::get('lat');
    Storage::disk ('local')->append ('lat__.txt', "lat:\r\n" . $lat);   
}
```

Comment: `Session::set` does not exist, you have to use `Session::put`. [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#storing-data)